Under what generality are the compactly supported singular and sheaf cohomologies equal?
Edit: I have since resolved my question.
If X is locally compact Hausdorff in addition to being cohomologically locally contractible with coefficients in $A$ - eg it is a manifold or an open subset of some locally finite CW complex - then, functorially in proper continuous maps between such spaces, compactly supported singular and sheaf cohomology coincide with coefficients in the Abelian group $A$. It requires only a minor addition to Sella’s argument (you can use the same flasque resolution they use), but I don’t have time to write it up right now.

I'm a little way into reading this nice paper by Yehonatan Sella, which claims - after minor generalisations I was able to see - the following:

Let the Abelian group $A$ be fixed. Let "clc" be the following property of topological spaces $X$: $$\forall x\in X,\,\forall n\in\Bbb N_0:\quad\varinjlim_{\quad\,\,U\ni x\\U\subseteq X\text{ is open }}\mathrm{H}^n_{\mathrm{sing}}(U,x;A)=0$$
There is a functorial isomorphism $\mathrm{H}^\bullet_{\mathrm{sing}}(-;A)\cong\mathscr{H}^\bullet(-;\underline{A})$ on the full subcategory of clc spaces, where $\underline{A}$ denotes the 'constant' sheaf functor.

The isomorphism is also natural in the group $A$. However, I'm quite fond of Iversen's book "Cohomology of Sheaves"; therein, compactly supported cohomology comes up often. I wonder to what extent we can have $\mathrm{H}^\bullet_{\mathrm{sing},C}(X;A)\cong\mathscr{H}^\bullet_C(X;\underline{A})$. It is certainly true when $X$ is a smooth manifold.
I expect a more general answer to this is known, but I haven't found anything.
The proof in Sella's paper goes as follows: a "functor" from spaces to complexes of sheaves is constructed, with the resulting $\mathscr{C}^\bullet_{X,A}$ being exact in positive degrees and having zeroth cohomology the sheaf $\underline{A}$. We prove the $\mathscr{C}^n_{X,A}$ are flabby/flasque sheaves, also, so we realise $\mathscr{H}^n(X;\underline{A})\cong\mathrm{H}^n\mathscr{C}^\bullet_{X,A}(X)$. However, in the construction there is a (surjective) quasiisomorphism $\mathrm{C}^\bullet_{\mathrm{sing}}(X;A)\to\mathscr{C}^\bullet_{X,A}(X)$, so we get the result (for individual $X$). Naturality in $X$ is not so hard to conclude either; if $f:X\to Y$ is a map of clc spaces there is a sheaf morphism $\mathscr{C}^\bullet_{Y,A}\to f_\ast\mathscr{C}^\bullet_{X,A}$ which satisfies the requirements of Scholium $2.5.2$ in Iversen and we realise this morphism computes $f^\ast$ on sheaf cohomology, but also that it is compatible with the usual restriction map $\mathrm{C}^\bullet_{\mathrm{sing}}(Y;A)\to\mathrm{C}^\bullet_{\mathrm{sing}}(X;A)$.
$\mathscr{C}^\bullet_{X,A}(U):=\varinjlim_{\eta\text{ is a nesting on }U}C^\bullet_\eta(U;A)$, the colimit being taken in Abelian groups, where $C^k_\eta$ and "nesting" are defined in the paper. Using naturality I'm able to conclude the following thing:

If $X$ is a Hausdorff clc space, $\mathrm{H}^\bullet_{\mathrm{sing},C}(X;A)\cong\mathrm{H}^\bullet(\varinjlim_{K\subseteq X\text{ compact }}\ker(\mathscr{C}_{X,A}^\bullet(X)\to\mathscr{C}^\bullet_{X,A}(X\setminus K)))$

But it is very unclear to me if that object in the parantheses can be construed as $\Gamma_C^\bullet$ of any kind of soft resolution of $\underline{A}$. We would have to assume $X$ to be LCH for that to work, too. I once saw it said that this is true for 'reasonable' spaces, but no reference or elaboration was given.
Does anyone here have a reference or elaboration? It is known if there is a (hopefully functorial) isomorphism between the two cohomologies for a broader class of space?

A simplified proof of the cited theorem has since then appeared in https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06927v3.

@DmitriPavlov I have seen that, but do not consider it simplified. I don't know the language of higher homotopy theory, hypersheaves and so on.

Sella's proof is 19 pages of technical arguments, whereas the cited proof occupies half a page (on page 4).  All the relevant facts about hypersheaves are present in the cited paper, so learning a small bit of the applicable background (which is also relevant and useful for other areas) seems like an easier task here.

@DmitriPavlov: It’s a lovely proof and definitely a good advertisement for the power of such homotopy-theoretic techniques — but I can see how a reader not at least somewhat familiar with them would find it rather unwelcoming.  Right out of the gate, it uses homotopy (co)limits and hypersheaves without either giving or referencing definitions for them.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Hypersheaves are defined in Definition 2.1.  Remark 2.2 explains that the homotopy limit can be computed as the totalization of a double complex (which can be taken as a definition without any problems).  For hypercovers, it gives a reference to Dugger–Hollander–Isaksen and Dugger–Isaksen, and further references are given in Remark 3.5.  So I wouldn't say it's unwelcoming.

@DmitriPavlov: My bad, I meant to write “hypercovers” not “hypersheaves” — the latter is indeed defined, but in terms of the former, which are not.  Sure, it cites DHI and DI (and various other excellent refs) at various points, but it doesn’t point to any one specifically as a source to find suitable definitions of hypercovers/-sheaves and homotopy colimits.  Put yourself in the shoes of someone who doesn’t know much of the homotopy-theoretic literature, trying to read this in a self-contained way: how would you know where to find these definitions, short of skimming all the cited literature?

To be clear, I think it’s a lovely paper — this isn’t a big complaint — but I think it’s most suited for readers who already know at least a bit of categorical homotopy theory (e.g. are comfortable with homotopy (co)limits) and are somewhat oriented in the literature.  For someone not familiar with that background, I don’t think it’s such an easy read — I can easily understand why OP bounced off it.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks for your.. mentalisation. I have tried to break into this kind of thing several times, and while I know some simplicial homotopy theory and have read chunks of Riehl's "categorical homotopy theory", I am none the wiser for these purposes

I don't think it answers your question, but if you like Iversen's book, then you might also like Bredon's book, which is a lot more systematic with proving theorems for cohomology with supports, treating the $H^i$ and $H^i_c$ statements simultaneously (and even more general than that). For instance, it treats Čech theory with compact support, which I think is missing in Iversen.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks for the suggestion. Looking at the front matter, it seems like the perfect follow-up book from Iversen.
